# Find random folder name that only contain number

Tags: c#

I am creating a software and I need your help.
I need to find a folder that the name is generated randomly.
It created in C:\MyFolder\123456789

I would like to store the folder name in a string.
Sometimes another folder could be created but I do not want to store it

C:\MyFolder\123456789

C:\MyFolder\MySecondFolder

I just would like to store

C:\MyFolder\123456789 in a string.

I tried :

`string MyFolder = Path.GetFileName(C:\MyFolder);
MessageBox.Show(MyFolder);`

But nothing.
Thanks in advance for the help !

Comment: Just to make it clear, you want to generate a random path?

Comment: Nah I am sorry for my english. I would like to get the folder name

Comment: You want to find a folder, or create a folder?  I'm not sure how you'd propose to find a folder unless you knew what you were looking for.

Comment: The code you've shown won't even compile.

Comment: I want to find a folder but I can't know the name I just know the path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\MyFolder");
string direcotryName = dirInfo.Name;
```

EDIT:
I think I understood your question

you want to find the directory that contains numbers - right?

```
DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\MyFolder");

int parsedInt;

DirectoryInfo foundDirectory = dirInfo.GetDirectories()
    .FirstOrDefault(di => int.TryParse(di.Name, out parsedInt));
 if (foundDirectory != null)
{
    MessageBox.Show(foundDirectory.Name)
}
```

EDIT2:
Supporting longer folders:

```
DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\MyFolder");

DirectoryInfo foundDirectory = dirInfo.GetDirectories()
    .FirstOrDefault(di => di.Name.All(char.IsNumber));
```

Comment: It show me : "MyFolder" if I try to MessageBox.Show(direcotryName);

Comment: I've edited my answer, I think I got what you're looking for

Comment: Last question, how to do if the folder name is more than 11 caracters ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
var nameLength = 10;
var rnd = new Random();
var randomName = string.Join("", Enumerable.Range(1, nameLength).Select(a => rnd.Next(0, 9).ToString()));
var path = Path.Combine(@"C:\MyFolder", randomName);
```

Comment: Good idea I think because the folders are created with the same number of caracters.

Comment: Oh I am sorry you didn't understood my question in fact

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Directory.EnumerateDirectories](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383304%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and test the directory name with [long.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zc2x2b1h%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

```
var folder = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\MyFolder");
long findFile;
var results = folder.EnumerateDirectories().Where(dir => long.TryParse(dir.Name, out findFile));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   try 
    {
       // this will get all the files in directory C:\MyFolder\ 

        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\MyFolder\", "*");
       // Iterate over all file names to check if it consists only numbers
        foreach (string file in files) 
        {
            bool isFileNameNumericOnly = true;
          // check if file name contains only numbers 
           // if yes then store the name of the file. 

             foreach (char c in file)
              {
                // This condition checks if a char is a digit or not
                 if (c < '0' || c > '9')
                  {
                    isFileNameNumericOnly = false;
                    break;
                  }
              }
              if(isFileNameNumericOnly == true)
              {
                 //here you can save the name of file
              }
         }

    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The process failed: {0}", e.ToString());
    }
```